# google chrome and diablo 3 taking to long to start

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome

I don't know if this is related but, a week ago, while working in chrome, I accidentally generated an infinite loop in javascript while debugging it in chrome. Chrome crashed and everything I've tried didn't work. I re-installed chrome several times and now, it is too slow starting up (taking some minutes to show) and some times, when opening new tabs, these tabs crash and I've to restart them... Today, trying to open diablo 3 it just won't run... The splash opens, displays the message "INITIALIZING..." and nothing happens... It just stays there... I'm running windows 8.

Is it related? Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Thank you

Comment: How much free space you have in the drive? What did your script do? My guess is that you've filled your drive with junk and forgot to delete it.

Comment: 148Gb free. The script read cookies and while retrieving JSON from several of them splited, a bug kept reading them non-stop...

Comment: Even when you uninstall google chrome from windows the per-user data does stay on the drive. I would go to C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Google and delete Chrome in that folder. And also if I were you unless your OS drive is SSD I would run some sort of a defrag tool (I use defraggler).